# Making Loading div accessible when the div is created

Tags: html, accessibility, roles, wai-aria

This container is created on the fly and added into the dom. The container is removed from the dom once the data is loaded. When this container is added into the dom and narrator/NVDA is on, I need to announce "Loading"

```
<div id="loadingContainer">
    <span id="spinner">
         <svg/>
    </span> 
    <div id="loadingText" aria-label="Loading...">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Tried role = "alert" for the loadingtext div but it announces "alert" which is not good for me. Tried role = "status" but it didnt announce anything, I presume because the container is created with the role attribute and there is no change in the value of the element.

Comment: Have you tried with aria-live attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Should be a simple matter of having a container for the container that's added with `aria-live="polite"`.  I always use `polite` for aria-live regions unless it's absolutely necessary for a message to be announced immediately, which is rarely needed.

So your code would just have

```
<div aria-live="polite">
  <!-- your newly created <div> will go here -->
</div>
```

And when the container is created, you'd have:

```
<div aria-live="polite">
  <div id="loadingContainer">
    <span id="spinner">
         <svg/>
    </span> 
    <div id="loadingText" aria-label="Loading...">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'd also have to change the value of [`aria-relevant`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-relevant) since the default is "*additions text*" which will only announce when you **add** the DOM element.  If you want an announcement made when you remove that DOM element, you'd need "*removals*" too.  Or simply use "*all*".

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
  <!-- your newly created <div> will go here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`role=“status”` would be most suited for conveying the text. Alternatively you can choose to have no `role` but add an `“aria-live=“assertive”`. Be sure that the container with `role=“status”`/`aria-live` is present from the start, when the page is loaded, and then give it some content when you would like it to be announced. You should do this, because Firefox + NVDA screen-reader does not immediately see when a new live area appears in the DOM. Having it present from the start is the surefire way to let the browser + screen-reader listen for changes in that element.

You can also consider setting `aria-busy=“true”` on the actual element being updated.

Also, having an `aria-label` with the same text as it’s content (“Loading…”) won’t have any effect. Just skip the label and keep the text.